# Кнопка в bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, datepicker

Я использую AngularJS и HTML. Подскажите как в календаре изменить функцию кнопки чтобы при нажатии на нее вызывалась моя функция. Сейчас при нажатии кнопки "ок", принимается дата.
Попробовал слушать событие

```
$('.date-picker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
   openDatePicker();
});
```

Подключил daterangepicker

```
<input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker"
 style="width: 200px;"
 ng-model="datePicker.date_range"/>

$scope.openDatePicker = function () {
    console.log('open')
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно весь код? пишите ангулар, а код jquery

Comment: Я подключил bootstrap daterangepicker директиву, кода то по сути нету, я думаю, что саму директиву не поправить

Comment: вы нашли в исходнике библиотеки, где вызывается дефолтное поведение нажатия на эту кнопку?

Comment: Да, clickApply: function(e) {
            this.hide();
            this.element.trigger('apply.daterangepicker', this);
        }

Comment: меня сейчас конечно закидают камнями, но когда мне нужно было изменить поведение, я поправил исходник daterangepicker и уже 1.5 года всё работает нормально в проекте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.date-picker').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $scope.openDatePicker();
});
```